# MS CRM 2016 - Lookup records default type

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, lookup, entities

How can I set default entity type and view in Lookup records?

For example I have default entity `Account` and some account view `My View 1`, but I can choose another entity `Contact` with let's say `My View 2`. How can I set, that the default entity will be `Contact`, not `Account`?

[image]

I've found that something like this should work:

```
document.getElementById("fieldid").setAttribute("defaulttype", "2");
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Only this works

```
document.getElementById("fieldid").setAttribute("lookuptypes", "2");
```

but there is a problem, that I can choose only `Contact` in this case, because `Account` is not there anymore. I know that I can put there more values with Account index number and just change an order, but in my case I have more than 30 entities there and I don't want to rewrite it all.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are following using `document.getElementById` is unsupported in CRM world as this code will break in future product release.

The supported method is as below:

```
var control = Xrm.Page.getControl("regardingobjectid");
control.getAttribute().setLookupTypes(["contact", "lead"]);
```

[Reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/186304)

Comment: I have already found this solution, but it does not work for me. control.getAttribute() returns me Mscrm.LookupAttributeWrapper which is ok I think, but the method setLookupTypes returns false and nothing changes.

Comment: And control.getAttribute().getLookupTypes() returns null.

Comment: @BananaCake sorry I don’t have 2016 version right away to test & assist you. Let me look in internet for such discussions..